# New Sheet is not getting created when i do Apache POI on a loop

Tags: java, spring, apache, hibernate, apache-poi

I am facing an issue when i write huge set of data to a Excel file with multiple sheets. I am using apache POI for the excel export.

```
    File file = new File("../path/file.xls");
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int limit = 100000,offset=0,count=0,sheetIndex=0;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    do{

        XSSFSheet sheet = null;
        if (file.exists() && sheetIndex > 0) {
            try {
                workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet-"+sheetIndex);
        }else{
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet-"+sheetIndex);
        }
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        //...Header row creation...
        List<DataType> result = query(criteria,offset,limit);
        offset = offset + limit;
        count = results.size();
        sheetIndex++;
        int rowCount = 1;
        for(DataType rowData : results){
            Row row =  sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            //row creation....
        }
        try {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.writeTo(fout);
        } finally {
            outputStream.flush();
        }

    }while(count == limit);

    workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.writeTo(fout);
    outputStream.close();
    fout.close();
```

In the loop i am fetching 100k records from DB and writing it to the excel, and each 100k i am creating a new Sheet until there are no more records from the DB.

This code have 2 issues
1. I am facing issues in opening the file, the excel file alert me that it has issues when i try to open, eventually when i say ok it loads the data.

2. I can see there are only 1 sheet with 100k data though my DB contains 240M records. I also can see the loop is looping for number of times.

How can i get these issues resolved? really stucked!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The `XSSFWorkbook workbook` is created multiple times and it overwrites the one created on previous loop. The workbook needs to be created only once.

I suggest changing the loop entry to the following:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
do {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet-"+sheetIndex);
    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    //...Header row creation...
    // remaining code
```

Comment: the check if a file already exists can be moved in before the loop. no need to omit it completely

Comment: Thank you @Antot yeah the solution works, but i have faced a huge lagging of time after 1M records precessed. Because all those data i really do not want to keep in memory (Assuming it is utilizing my heap space).

Comment: @user3247425: you are welcome. I think that lagging is already another problem, related with the amount of data to process and save. I also think that there are ways to improve the current code.

Comment: I am more concerned on the memory management part, since this code can be hit by multiple users simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed WorkBook type to SXSSFWorkbook and set the flush limit to 100 and it worked.
The performance has increased 5 times better than the XSSFWorkbook.